# Como agregar BootstrapCDN a Seaside Pharo

Tags: bootstrap, smalltalk, pharo

Queria consular si hay alguna manera de agregar librerias css a seaside (pharo) directamente agregando el link en el head.
Tengo un proyecto con seaside 3 y queria ver de agregarle bootstrap 4 a partir de su cdn.
Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la respuesta es si, pero no me acuerdo como :)
mucho mejor si preguntas en la lista (Pharo-users) o en discord (si, en inglés... aunque en el discord hay un channel en español).
los datos de conexión están acá: http://pharo.org/community